# StoryBoard actions cannot be targeted at repeating content

Tags: ios, storyboard

in storyBoard I add a uitapgesturerecognizer to a imageView. this imageView in a custom cell . but xcode tip me:Actions cannot be targeted at repeating content.
why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: Your specific situation is effectively a limitation of the storyboard, you need to add the gesture in a different way, into a custom cell

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya look  i update image  in my question